# Full Screen Image header - Responsive Setting

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

I have a full screen featured image header on my home page, which I am trying to make responsive.  The width of the image seems to cut off on different screen sizes

I have tried this height and width setting, but would like the image itself to "resize" responsively.

```
.hero-small {
    height: 886px!important;
    width: auto;
}
```

[Website Link](http://entertheedge.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something you can look up that will help

1. `width: 100%;`
2. `background-size:cover`
3. `background-size:contain`
4. or use media queries such as `screen and (max-width: 500px) {}` to adjust each break point with specific background-size/position

hope this help